# C# Class library and Reporting

Tags: c#, class, reporting

I am building a big system, which i have divided in three tiers, UI, Class-Library, and Database.
Database stores all data only, and Class-Library provides all functionalities and business logic.
And UI is the User-Interface.

The issue which i face is: how to integrate the reporting in this situation.
I am using C# for class-library, and windows-forms-in-C# for UI.
I intend to use rdlc Microsoft reports.

My strategy at this point is:
Let every object add its own data in a dataset,
which will be then returned to the UI for display in report.

Comment: Metro, I interpretted his question as: What best practices would you recommend to continue the business logic separation that he already has?

Comment: The actual question is: what is the best strategy for reporting and getting report-data in a multi-tier application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the reports are just another UI. Your business logic for what data to return for a given report should live in the class library. The reporting business objects would probably live in a namespace of their own (Appname.Reporting). I think I would have an abstract report class that provides a skeleton for most properties and methods that a report would need, and subclass that skeleton for each individual report. Thus, one class per report, but all derived from a generic class.

Comment: I liked the idea of abstract class to provide a skeleton and common interface. This will simplify everything.